# Can I use the attached weapons on the Dewbauchee JB 700?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I purchased the Dewbauchee Jb 700 for $305,000 but the guns don’t work. However, it’s also on Warstock cache and carry website for $1,470,000. What’s the difference? If I purchase the million dollar Dewbauchee JB 700 will the guns work? Also, can I use the guns outside of online missions?

Answer (score 2):

The [JB700](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/JB_700) is a decommissioned version of the car you can buy from Legendary Motorsports, meaning the weapons don't work.  But, the [JB700W](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/JB_700W), is the weaponized version from War Stock Cache and Carry.

The GTA Online section for the Wiki says:

> The JB 700W can be modified with a small set of weapons, which improve
>   its defensive capabilities to a certain extent:
>
> - It can equip two driver-controlled machine guns on its front, which
>     perform the same as those of vehicles, such as the Blazer Aqua and
>     Ruiner 2000, providing decent firepower against players and vehicles
>     with none or light armour, but will struggle with heavily-armoured
>     vehicles.
> - The vehicle has the option to install Proximity Mines.
>     Unlike Weaponized Vehicles added in the Gunrunning update and the
>     Arena War vehicles from the Arena War update, the vehicle has two
>     different Proximity Mine choices: Spike and Slick;
>
>   - The Spike option
>       (dark blue flashing light) bursts the tyres of vehicles passing over
>       or near it, as well as dealing a small amount of damage to the
>       vehicle, mainly affecting the vehicle's windows, but otherwise dealing
>       no damage or force. The mine does not burst vehicles with bulletproof
>       tyres installed.
>   - The Slick option (green flashing light) bursts a
>       large amount of oil on the surface, causing vehicles passing over it
>       to lose control. This deals no damage to both vehicles or players.